Finding number of dissimilar terms in an expansion
The question is
The number of dissimilar terms in the expansion of $(1+x^3+x^4)^4$ is ?
Upon using the formula $^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$ or using permutation & combination, I am getting 15 as the answer but the correct answer is $\boxed{14}$
Where have I gone wrong??

How do you get that formula? What is $n$ and $r$?

@ultralegend5385 The formula is derived using partition method of Combinatorics. n is the power of the bracket and r is the number of terms in the bracket.

Are you sure it works in this scenario? What are the conditions for the formula to work?

@ultralegend5385 When the terms inside the bracket are distinct numbers

That cannot be since it doesn't work in this case. I think you should probably try to see what doesn't work in the derivation in this case, and try to fix that.

The general formula
$$
(a+b+c)^4=a^4 + 4 a^3 b + 4 a^3 c + 6 a^2 b^2 + 12 a^2 b c + 6 a^2 c^2 + 4 a b^3 + 12 a b^2 c + 12 a b c^2 + 4 a c^3 + b^4 + 4 b^3 c + 6 b^2 c^2 + 4 b c^3 + c^4
$$
has 15 terms and it could be proven using combinatorial argument.
However numbers $a=1, b=x^3, c=x^4$ in your bracket are not “independent” as general numbers $a,b,c$ from formula above. Terms
$$
b^4=(x^3)^4=x^{12}
$$
and
$$
4ac^3=4(1)(x^4)^3=4x^{12}
$$
add up together to the term
$$
5x^{12}
$$
and that is why your expansion has one term less than general one $(a+b+c)^4$.
But it should be pointed that answering question about number of terms in expansion
$(1+x^3+x^4)^n$ for general positive integer  $n$ is much harder.

Isn't there any mathematical way to do this because it's almost impossible to see such corner cases with naked eyes

I think easier would be start with examining expansion $(1+x+x^2)^n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Coefficients of this expansion are numbers from trinomial triangle https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialCoefficient.html.
